# How do I get a list of CSVs in a folder?

Tags: r

My project directory looks like this:

```
inputData/
script.R
```

In `inputData`, I have eight CSV files. I want to loop through all CSV files in `inputData/`.

I've tried this code...

```
dir.input <- "inputData/"
filenames <- dir(dir.input, pattern="*.csv")
```

... but `filenames` is just an empty character.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please note that pattern is a regular expression, not wildcard expression, so you should use `pattern=".+\\.csv$"`, anyway I don't think that's the problem... have you tried to remove pattern arguments and see if you're looking in the right folder ?

Comment: Your working directory probably isn't what you think it is. Provide the absolute path, or check using `setwd` or `getwd`

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `setwd("/absolute/path/to/my/project-directory")` before the rest of my code.